# In-App Purchases and Upgrading iOS Apps

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Say in my app I'm selling cats for $.99, dogs for $.99, and birds for $.99. Or, you can buy all 3 at a discounted price of $1.99. The "buy all" would have its own product id within iTunes Connect.

Now, say I do an update. I've added fish for $.99 and horses for $.99. Now, to "buy all" I would want to charge more, say $2.99.

So what if person A does not install this update?

When they go to "buy all", they would get charged $2.99 because I have increased the price in iTunesConnect to reflect the fact that they now get 5 sets of animals. But person A would only get the 3 sets at the price of 5, and would not be happy.

Am I missing something or is this just a flawed scenario? The only option I see is to create different "buy all" product ids for every single update, but that would quickly become unmanageable. Are there any alternatives, besides forcing an update?

Comment: You are correct in that you'd have to create different buy all product id's if you don't want outdated apps to have the higher price of newer updates.

Comment: Another option would be to force a user to upgrade before they can perform an in-app purchase. Your app will need code to check a version value stored on your web server. Of course this doesn't help users with the current version since this code doesn't exist. But this approach can be used going forward and only requires the one additional "buy all" product id.

Comment: @rmaddy Everybody loves race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I really hate apps that force updates. Persistent nagging is bad too — in one app, it nagged *three times* on each launch (I think they fixed that bug in an update).

#### If the purchase is non-consumable...

You're doing something that IAP doesn't really support: There's currently no analogue for buying an "album" that also marks individual tracks as owned so they can't be inadvertently re-bought.

That said,

- If buying the combo in 1.0 *shouldn't* give you fish+horse in 1.1, then you need either a new product or a consumable product.
- If the user who bought the cat+dog+bird combo in version 1.0 should get cat+dog+bird+fish+horse in version 1.1, it's probably fine. It will fix itself if the user updates the app.

I'll assume the latter: The user is buying "all animals" which automatically gives new animals in new versions of the app.

(and you could remind the user to update — just don't be too annoying!).

I would not worry too much in this case — my gut feeling is that users with phones too old to update are unlikely to purchase apps, let alone IAPs, and users who purposefully avoid updating probably won't buy IAPs either.

A reminder might be useful here ("by the way, this also unlocks fish+horse in version 1.1") — just make sure you don't block the UI.

#### If the purchase is consumable...

There are two possibilities.

- **The price changes before the user updates the app.** The user's account gets credited with cat+dog+bird.

  You might be able to fix this when the user updates the app, but there doesn't seem to be a reliable way to tell which version of the IAP the user bought: you could try storing `SKProduct.{price,priceLocale}` along with the receipt, but there's no guarantee that the price you read from the product is the same as the price paid in the transaction. Oh well.

  The price doesn't seem to be in the transaction receipt either, according to the iOS [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1)
- **The user updates the app before the price changes.** The user can buy the 1.1 combo at the 1.0 price!

I don't think you can ensure that the IAP price change happens in sync with the app update becoming available; attempting to force an upgrade may simply make some users frustrated because the upgrade isn't available yet. The only safe option appears to be the second, though it may lose some revenue.

However, since the user is fundamentally buying different things, they really ought to be different products.

(In the non-consumable case they're the "same thing" in the sense that what you get does not depend on the version you bought it in.)